# Given the initial working memory WM={(lista e b a c d e a) (lista1 a c a d e e f g)} and the rule R1, show the state of the final WM

Tags: clips

```
(defrule R1 
      ?f <‐ (lista  $?x ?a $?y)
            (lista1  $?p ?a $?q ?a  $?r)

      => 
          
          (retract ?f)
          (assert (lista $?x $?y)))
```

A. {(lista  e b a c d f g)  (lista1 a c a d e e f g)} 
B. {(lista b) (lista1 a c a d e e f g) } 
**C. {(lista  b c d) (lista1 a c a d e e f g)}** 
D. {(lista  e b a c d) (lista1)}

I understand that **lista1** remains unchanged, but why only **b,c,d** remain in **lista**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables that occur more than once in patterns must have the same value in order for the rule to be matched. The variable **?a** occurs once in the first pattern and twice in the second pattern. The multifield variables **$?x**, **$?y**, **$?p**, **$?q**, and **$?r** all occur once each so because of their positioning these will just bind to any remaining values in the patterns not matched by **?a**. The actions of the rule will then remove any value that was found at least twice in **lista1** and also in **lista**.

```
         CLIPS (6.4 2/9/21)
CLIPS> 
(defrule R1 
   ?f <- (lista  $?x ?a $?y)
   (lista1  $?p ?a $?q ?a  $?r)
   =>        
   (retract ?f)
   (assert (lista $?x $?y)))
CLIPS> (watch facts)
CLIPS> (assert (lista e b a c d e a) (lista1 a c a d e e f g))
==> f-1     (lista e b a c d e a)
==> f-2     (lista1 a c a d e e f g)
<Fact-2>
CLIPS> (run)
<== f-1     (lista e b a c d e a)
==> f-3     (lista e b a c d e)
<== f-3     (lista e b a c d e)
==> f-4     (lista b a c d e)
<== f-4     (lista b a c d e)
==> f-5     (lista b c d e)
<== f-5     (lista b c d e)
==> f-6     (lista b c d)
CLIPS>
```

Comment: one more question, "then remove any value that was found at least **twice** in lista1 and also in lista". what would happen if **?a** was used 2 times in lista and 3 times in lista1. how many occurrences would be removed? I assume only more than two.

Comment: It would depend upon where ?a was added, whether you put additional multifield variables in the patterns, and what the initial working memory was.